# Cleaning up after exceptions (as explained in Eloquent JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

In the first edition of the book Eloquent JavaScript, in page 67 there is the following code, under the subchapter "Cleaning up after Exceptions":

```
var currentThing = null;

function processThing(thing) {
    var prevThing = currentThing;
    currentThing = thing;
    /* do complicated processing... */
    currentThing = prevThing;
}
```

What is the logic of reassign `prevThing` to `currentThing` in the end?

Here is, we already assigned `currentThing` to `prevThing`, and then changed `currentThing` to `thing`, so what is the taste in the last reassignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last assignment is not useless because `currentThing` is a global variable.

To make a point, the author proposes some hypothetical scenario that, for a moment, while `/* do complicated processing... */`  takes place, you want to have the value of `thing` exposed globally (via `currentThing`) for others to consume.

After the processing, the author tells that in such hypothetical scenario, you wanted to restore `currentThing` to its value before the processing started (the value stored in `prevThing`).

All of this happens in the context of ***Error Handling***. The author creates such complicated scenario to tell you that if you want to **reset some variable after some calculation** you should **wrap the calculation in a `try` block** and **do the reset in a `finally`** as such:

```
var currentThing = null;

function processThing(thing) {
    var prevThing = currentThing;
    currentThing = thing;
    try {
      /* do complicated processing... */
    } finally {
      // now you'll reset currentThing to its previous value,
      // no matter if the complicated processing errors or not
      currentThing = prevThing;
    }
}
```

So that any errors the complicated processing might throw won't affect the resetting of `currentThing`.

Comment: **tl;dr** the author creates such scenario to introduce and justify the `finally` block in JavaScript.

Comment: I find your answer very didactic and helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that if in `/* do complicated processing... */` you want to call other functions in the same scope, but for some reason prefer or cannot pass the `thing` as an argument to them, the `currentThing` variable makes the object available to those functions. Once the complicated processing is done, `currentThing` can either be set back to the previous value or more properly `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This will show [null, n] for all iterations. So it may be a mistake in code.

```
var currentThing = null;

function processThing(thing) {
  var prevThing = currentThing;
  currentThing = thing;

  console.log(prevThing, currentThing);

  currentThing = prevThing;
}

var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

data.forEach(processThing);
```

If you want to access item from prev iteration, you need to correct it a little.

```
var prevThing = null;

function processThing(currentThing) {
  /* do complicated processing... */
  console.log(prevThing, currentThing);

  prevThing = currentThing;
}

var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

data.forEach(processThing);
```